# C# ToolStrip label sometimes printing last character first

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this line of code that doesn't seem to print correctly:

`toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = String.Format("Done ({0} results)", _count);`

And it prints out like so: 
[image: Example image]

It also prints ".Done" if no String.Format is applied:
`toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Done.";`

But it prints fine if just given "Done" (it doesn't print 'eDon'):

But the String.Format seems to run fine (the relevant code is in the background)
[image: Example 2]

What's up with that?

Comment: This could be a problem with autosizing. Could you try a "narrow" character at the end of your string, say, 'l', '1', or 'I', and see if it gets moved to the front? MS says autosizing problem happens only to the first label, so if you add a second label and keep the first empty, the problem might go away.

Comment: I added a second label and used it (and kept the first blank) and had no change.  Additionally, neither a lowercase "L" or the number "1" reproduce the issue but using an exclamation work does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when you set the control's RightToLeft property to True.  That's a property that was intended to render text properly for users that speak Hebrew or Arabic, languages whose script is written right-to-left.  Problem is, you are not displaying any Hebrew or Arabic, "Done" is English.  Those languages render foreign words left-to-right.  But not parentheses.

You'll have to set RightToLeft back to False and achieve layout another way.

Comment: That fixed it but RightToLeft defaults to "Yes."  Does this property simply state "Draw RTL if requested" or something else?

Comment: It doesn't default to Yes, it defaults to the parent control's setting for that property.  So your StatusStrip or Form has the property set to Yes.  It means "Render text properly for languages with a right-to-left text rendering direction".  The rules for which are pretty intricate.

Comment: Ah, yes you're right.  I had the StatusStrip set to "RightToLeft" thinking it just shifted the control alignment. Thanks!